# measure network bandwidth of command line app or script

Tags: linux, networking, bash, wget, bandwidth

How can I "box" a command line app or a script im running,  to tell how much bandwidth it used?

e.g. I want to run `wget -rk http://example.com`. Now this example is easy, since wget can report it's own bandwidth. But if im invoking several `wget` instances in a script, that requires me to start writing code to add the numbers up. If i'm using additional tools in the script that use the network, i need to make sure to add into the calculation the bandwidth that they generate.

This sounds complex, and I'm wondering if I could just `measurebandwidthAndExecute ./script.sh`?

Comment: some of the answers to [this question on unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34116/how-can-i-limit-the-bandwidth-used-by-a-process) may be relevant, particularly the one on pv / pipe viewer?